# Git - push to new remote with a single consolidated commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

I have been working on a private repo for a while, and am going to release to GitHub.

The problem is i've got many many commits, and for hygiene's sake I'd like only a single commit to appear in GitHub.

How do I push without pushing history? i.e consolidate the entire MASTER into a single commit

many thanks in advance.

Doug

Answer (score 5):

Usually one would use `git rebase --interactive HEAD~n` where n is the no. of commits you want to merge into one. However, in your case you want to squash the entire history into a single commit and since rebasing without a parent (upto the initial commit) isn't possible we have to use `git reset` and `git commit --amend`.

Here's what you do:

1. `git log --oneline`. Find the SHA of your initial commit.
2. Suppose our SHA is `fe7d5d1`. Run `git reset fe7d5d1`. This will reset the branch to the inital commit.
3. Now use `git add .` to stage all your changes.
4. Next amend your inital commit, `git commit --amend -m "Initial commit"`.
5. Confirm that you only have a single commit now with `git log --oneline`.

**CAUTION**: Never rewrite/squash/rebase commits you have already pushed to a remote repo.

Comment: what if I have pushed the whole history to a private repo at bitbucket, but just want to push the current state (ie rebased) to github?

Comment: The idea is never to rewrite history that has already propagated to others. In your case, if only you have access to the private repo it's safe to rebase.

Comment: I can't just rewrite history for the GitHub repo and keep history for BitBucket? i.e "Commit" all my current changes as a single commit?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend such a work flow. In fact, I would consider this all-commits-squashed-into-one as a one-time only activity. You don't want to do this all the time. Squashing 2-3 related commits into one is common, but not the entire branch. Commit history is important and must always be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Look into git rebase. Interactive mode.